# Stack icons in fontawesome

Tags: jquery, css, font-awesome

I display grid icons using the font awesome framework. Is there a way of stacking the icons so i can display a `3x2` grid icon?

**Demo [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JfGVE/1323/)**

```
<a href="./"><i class="fa fa-square"></i> 1x1</a>
<a href="./" ><i class="fa fa-square"></i><i class="fa fa-square"></i> 2x1</a>
<a href="./"><i class="fa fa-th-large"></i> 2x2</a>
<a href="./"><i class="fa fa-th-large"></i> 3x2</a> << can not create 3 x 2
<a href="./"><i class="fa fa-th"></i> 3x3</a>
```

Comment: Are you talking about this: http://fontawesome.io/examples/#stacked

Comment: I dont think that this will work. Maybe with negative margins and stuff. But this isn´t as clear as it should be. I would create that icon by myself and include it as an image or icon.

Comment: refer to bootstrap grid layout ,https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no icon for that exact purpose, but you might manipulate the icons by moving them with margins so you'll eventually end up with what you need, it is really hacky tho.

```
<a href="./"><i class="fa fa-th-large"></i><i class="fa fa-th-large"></i> 3x2</a>

.fa-th-large ~ .fa-th-large{
  margin-left: -8px;
}
```

Comment: Good idea! But what's about `left: -6px;  position:relative;`?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, just scrambled together a quick example that comes close to what OP actually needs, now that they know how they can do it, i'm sure they'll resolve it :)

Comment: Sorry for the vagueness :) I wanted to say about `.fa-th-large ~ .fa-th-large {  left: -7px; position: relative; }` Icon becomes neater for my taste. http://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/bnwajmhc/

Comment: Oh, I understand. Please correct the typo. It should be `margin-left` instead of `maring-left`.

Comment: You're right, that's better, as said, just wanted a quick example :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to do some margin-left trick here to work around, like this

**Your HTML Code (for 3x2 icon)**

```
<a href="./"><i class="fa fa-th-large"></i><i class="fa fa-th-large over-lap"></i> 3x2</a>
```

**Relative CSS code will be like this**

```
.over-lap{
  margin-left:-7px; 
}
```

What you have to?

1. Add another 2x2 icon
2. create a class with some margin-left trick (here which is **.over-lap with negative left margin**)
3. Apply this class to the second icon, that's it.(vary the margin according to your requirement.)

Comment: Pretty much copy pasta of my answer, eh?

Comment: Sorry for this one, but thats not the case. When I opened comment box was busy in other work and get back to the comment box later. Meanwhile you posted with same answer.

Comment: I will delete my answer. :-)

Comment: No offense, i just don't like people with plagiarozing intent, naturally. FYI, you can see if someone posts a new answer while you are editing :)